# MySQL UPDATES get progressively slower

Tags: mysql, database

I have an application using a MySQL database hosted on one machine and 6 clients running on other machines that read and write to it over a local network.

I have one main work table which contains about 120,000 items in rows to be worked on. Each client grabs 40 unallocated work items from the table (marking them as allocated), does the work and then writes back the results to the same work table. This sequence continues until there is no more work to do.

[image]

The above is a picture that shows the amount of time taken to write back each block of 40 results to the table from one of the clients using UPDATE queries. You can see that the duration is fairly small for most of the time but suddenly the duration goes up to 300 sec and stays there until all work completes. This rapid increase in time to execute the queries towards the end is what I need help with.

The clients are not heavily loaded. The server is a little loaded but it has 16GB of RAM, 8 cores and is doing nothing other than hosting this db.

Here is the relevant SQL code.

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE work (
     item_id MEDIUMINT,
     item VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8,
     allocated_node VARCHAR(50),
     allocated_time DATETIME,
     result TEXT);
/* Then insert 120,000 items, which is quite fast. No problem at this point. */
INSERT INTO work VALUES (%s,%s,%s,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Client allocating 40 items to work on:

```
UPDATE work SET allocated_node = %s, allocated_time=NOW()
       WHERE allocated_node IS NULL LIMIT 40;
SELECT item FROM work WHERE allocated_node = %s AND result IS NULL;
```

Update the row with the completed result (this is the part that gets really slower after a few hours of running):

```
/* The chart above shows the time to execute 40 of these for each write back of results */
UPDATE work SET result = %s WHERE item = %s;
```

I'm using MySQL on Ubuntu 14.04, with all the standard settings.
The final table is about 160MB, and there are no indexes.

I don't see anything wrong with my queries and they work fine apart from the whole thing taking twice as long as it should overall.

Can someone with experience in these matters suggest any configuration settings I should change in MySQL to fix this performance issue or please point out any issues with what I'm doing that might explain the timing in the chart.

Thanks.

Comment: How big does `work` become?  What are the values of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `key_buffer_size`?  What Engine is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an index the complete table is scanned. If the item id gets larger a greater amount of the table has to be scanned to get the row to be updated.
I would try an index perhaps even the primary key for item_id?

Still the increase of duration seems too high for such a machine and relativly small database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that the index will make it faster to find the row to update, but if that were the issue shouldn't I expect a linear increase in time? The chart indicates some threshold after which the duration of the updates is drastically longer.

Comment: Both your and Iserni's answer were correct. Adding an index on 'item' solved the performance issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that more details would be required for a proper diagnosing (see below), I see two potential performance decrease possibilities here.

One is that you're running into a Schlemiel the Painter's Problem which you could ameliorate with

```
CREATE INDEX table_ndx ON table(allocated_node, item);
```

but it looks unlikely with so low a cardinality. MySQL shouldn't take so long to locate unallocated nodes.

A more likely explanation could be that you're running into a locking conflict of some kind between clients. To be sure, during those 300 seconds in which the system is stalled, run

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

from an administrator connection to MySQL. See what it has to say, and possibly use it to update your question. Also, post the result of

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
```

against the tables you're using.

You should be doing something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
allocate up to 40 nodes using SELECT...FOR UPDATE;
COMMIT WORK;
-- The two transactions serve to ensure that the node selection can
-- never lock more than those 40 nodes. I'm not too sure of that LIMIT
-- being used in the UPDATE.

START TRANSACTION;
select those 40 nodes with SELECT...FOR UPDATE;
<long work involving those 40 nodes and nothing else>
COMMIT WORK;
```

If you use a single transaction and table level locking (even implicitly), it might happen that one client locks all others out. In theory this ought to happen only with MyISAM tables (that only have table-level locking), but I've seen threads stalled for ages with InnoDB tables as well.

Comment: I'm not using any explicit locking currently, but I think you're saying that even so, locking could be happening implicitly? Also I'm not familiar with using transactions. Does transaction 2 lock the table from being accesses until the transaction completes? In which case the other clients would be blocked?

Comment: In theory a SELECT shouldn't block and an UPDATE on an InnoDB table only lock the affected rows. In practice I've seen complex UPDATEs with SELECTs and subqueries lock *all involved tables* - that's why I tend to perhaps over-use temporary and MEMORY tables to simplify queries. To be really sure about what's happening, though, you need to check the process list and maybe even the engine status.

Comment: Thank you. What's your recommendation for checking the "engine status"?

Comment: You need the appropriate privileges, then you may issue a SHOW ENGINE command. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-engine.html

Comment: Both your and Mairu's answer were correct. Adding an index on 'item' solved the performance issue. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not too sure our answers, even if helpful, did really hit the nail on the head. As you yourself observed, the graph for a repeated sequential scan ought to be different (more alike to a parabolic curve, instead of a flat "S" shape). I suspect that while the indexing does help, and maybe enough to cover and prevent it, another effect is still there. With luck, though, it will only resurface with much larger cardinalities.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'external locking' technique sounds fine.

`INDEX(allocated_node)` will help significantly for the first `UPDATE`.

`INDEX(item)` will help significantly for the final `UPDATE`.

(A compound index with the two columns will help only one of the updates, not both.)

The reason for the sudden increase:  You are continually filling in big `TEXT` fields, making the table size grow.  At some point the table is so big that it cannot be cached in RAM.  So, it goes from being cached to being a full table scan.

`...; SELECT ... FOR UPDATE; COMMIT;` -- The `FOR UPDATE` is useless since the `COMMIT` happens immediately.

You could play with the "40", though I can't think why a larger or smaller number would help.